# Using ng-repeat to loop through an array that is formatted like a string

Tags: php, angularjs, arrays, json

I have recently started adding Angular to an old app I made. Part of the app stores a json encoded array in a single cell in a mySql table. I know this is frowned upon, but I'm 100% sure it won't come back to bite me later. In the past I've just been able to do a json_decode on the array and output the values in an ordered list. Since I've included Angular, the data is being encoded and echoed at the end of the php file. It is then picked up by the Angular code and I'm able to loop through this deeply nested multidimensional object until it gets to this part...

```
"sub_items":"[\"subOne\",\"subTwo\",\"subThree\"]"
```

The closest I can get is to output the string including all the backslashes, brackets and quotes which makes sense because it is a string.

I've tried doing a json_decode on every instance of sub_items, but it's not working. I think that's because the whole thing just gets encoded again.

How might I be able to loop through this array?

**EDIT**

I have made some progress with the following based on comments in the answer from @Yaser Adel Mehraban.

```
foreach($master as $index => $item) {
    if($category == $item['category']) {
        $sub = [];
        $sub['sub_items'] = json_decode($item['sub_items']);
        unset($item['sub_items']);
        array_push($items, $item, $sub);
    }
}
```

This returns

```
...created_at":"2016-11-01 14:19:07"},{"sub_items":["subOne","subTwo","subThree"...
```

The formatting of the array I was having trouble with is correct now I think, but it's sitting outside the item. I have tried to array_merge as well, but it adds a new key which would force an unnecessary ng-repeat to step down I think. Suggestions...

Comment: did you tried the | json pipe?

Comment: what you are showing should decode just fine using json_decode() with array option set true. How deep is the whole array/object?

Comment: Split the String object and then use JSON.parse( "[\"subOne\",\"subTwo\",\"subThree\"]") to get the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it sorted with the following change...

```
foreach($master as $index => $item) {
    foreach($item as $key => $value) {
        if($key == 'sub_items') {
            $sub = json_decode($value);
            unset($item['sub_items']);
            $item['sub_items'] = $sub;
        }
    }
    if($category == $item['category']) {
        array_push($items, $item);                  
    }
}
```

This returned...

```
...created_at":"2016-11-01 14:19:07","sub_items":["subOne","subTwo","subThree"...
```

No longer treated as a string it's easy to loop through with Angular. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED:

You should decode using array options and then iterate through them using ng-repeat, however to get decode working you first need to split your string and get the second part:

```
$subItemsStr = explode('"sub_items":"[\"subOne\",\"subTwo\",\"subThree\"]"')[1];
$subItems = json_decode($subItemsStr, true);
```

Then you can use it.

Comment: you can't pass javascript variables to php method or assign the return of that php function directly to javascript either. They run in different environments at different times

Comment: @charlietfl I totally forgot to not write JS code when using json_decode :)

Comment: but you are also interpreting *"get to this part"* as being a string literal when it is probably part of the whole json structure

Comment: I think the whole problem is that Op is exceeding default depth limits of json_decode

Comment: The above code runs in the online php editor I've tried @charlietfl

Comment: right...it would, but I doubt that you would have direct access to that whole string including the property name....it would be nested in the whole json structure and OP has copied it as sample from within the larger structure

Comment: I think @charlietfl and Yaser Adel Mehraban may both be right. Yes, this is just a sample of a much larger structure. I'm pulling it from the db via Eloquent and I've been reorganizing it (grouping into categories and doing some basic addition) in order to make output via Angular much easier. Could I implement the solution above inside a foreach?

Comment: @user2530671 sure you could recursively walk through the whole php array , but have you tried setting `depth` option of json_decode?

Comment: Another solution is to send the json to client side and try JSON object to convert it back to array @user2530671

Comment: @charlietfl What is the default depth for json_decode? Encode is 512 I think. I'm nowhere close to that. The state the array is in when I've been trying to decode, is only 2 layers deep. I'm adding the rest of the complexity later on.

Comment: Ok...you did say it was deeply nested. Sounds like you might be merging JSON to array then somewhere in your processsing and not decoding it right there before merging

Comment: @YaserAdelMehraban I'd like to handle it in the php file if possible.

Comment: @charlietfl Yes I did. In the db it looks like `["subOne","subTwo","subThree"]`. so I'm guessing the extra slashes are coming from that last json_encode. I need to decode first (index would also be nice) as soon as I grab the data from the db.

Comment: @user2530671 that's right, decode first, do your operations and encode at last to keep the json consistent

Comment: yes...exactly...what you are actually seeing is json_encode( json) not json_encode(array)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
  var jsonObj = { 
    "sub_items":"[\"subOne\",\"subTwo\",\"subThree\"]"
  }

  var jsonString = jsonObj.sub_items;
  $scope.items = JSON.parse(jsonString);
});

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this, but I'd rather get what I want from the php to start with. I'm pretty new to Angular, but I do need to do some math on some of what's returned so I may end up having to do something like this later on. Thanks!